# Solving 2nd order differential equation with non zero right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on Clohessy–Wiltshire equations where a second order differential equation is to be solved. I am not sure whether this is homogeneous form or not. I just couldnot follow the intermediate steps. The method towards solution would be greatly appreciated.

$$\ddot x + n^2x = 2n\left(\dot y_0 + 2nx_0\right)$$

To obtain this

$$x(t) = \frac{\dot{x}_0}n\sin nt - \left(\frac{2\dot y_0}n + 3x_0\right)\cos nt+\left(\frac{2\dot y_0}n + 4x_0\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You state a particular solution at the end, rather than the general solution, but you didn't specify any initial or boundary conditions. You should either specify such conditions or, if there aren't any, the solution should be the general solution, which for a second-order equation contains two free parameters.

Comment: @joriki The OP's boundary conditions are clearly $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=\dot{x}_0$

Comment: @almagest: Now that you said it, it makes sense. It's a bit unusual though that an initial value occurs in the differential equation, so it wouldn't hurt to introduce them for clarity.